# Can some explain this code, that helped me to solve this error " is not clickable at point (1158, 533). Other element would receive the click"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to click on button system throws this error message.
    " is not clickable at point (1158, 533). Other element would receive the click"

I am trying to click on button which is in span tag but find this error " is not clickable at point (1158, 533). Other element would receive the click" 
above mention code helped to fix this issue, can someone explain this code? what is argument in this code? can we any value to arguments?

before that I am trying this code

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"get_approval\"]/span/span")).click();

This code help to solve this issue
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"get_approval\"]/span/span"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to know what does argutments[0] refer to. Arguments[0] refers to the first parameter in the executor.executeScript() method call. It refers to webElement ele to be more specific. Which in turn means you are doing ele.click()

Comment: In some web applications, click action cannot be performed via Selenium's click method call. So we perform indirect click using Javascript's click method call.

Answer (score 0):

I can think about 3 options:

1. Your selector is incorrect, i.e. your [span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) is wrapped in another element in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) so you need to verify the DOM tree to ensure that it is not "overlapped" by another element. Normally you should not be clicking the `<span>`, my expectation is that it should be a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) or [button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) or [image](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)
2. Element is hidden with some popup, i.e. [Cookie Consent](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/blog/cookie-consent-examples/) which needs to be clicked first
3. The element you're intending to click is not visible or fully visible, consider invoking [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function

   ```
   driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
   ```

---

4. Also try to avoid using wildcards in XPath like `//*` as it takes a lot of memory and resources to evaluate them. The best option is using IDs and once you locate the parent element you can go for a [relative XPath query](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("get_approval")).findElement(By.xpath("./span/span"));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help